# stale session data - websphere

Tags: session, websphere, session-replication

I'm having a stale attribute with the http session within Websphere 6 and may be related to in memory session replication..

Steps:

1. Object A.0 - Placed into the session with ID "ABC"
2. Remove A.0 from the session..
3. Object A.1 (New instance) - placed into Session with ID "ABC"
4. retrieve object with ID "ABC" from the session - RESULT: A.1 (Correct)
5. carry out a Servlet forward or a redirect (issues seen on both functions)..
6. retrieve "ABC" from the session - RESULT: A.0, the object that was removed from the session..

Notes -

- Same Session object (hashcode/session ID) used in steps 1-5 using in
  memory replication across 2 JVMs (single cluster)
- time duration    between steps 2 & 5 is total of 4 seconds
- No other external threads have accessed the session in the interim..
- Only noticed for 1 specific use-case; haven't encountered this in
  other use-cases..

Anyone seen anything like this before where a stale data is being returned from the websphere application server?

Thanks,

Ian.

Comment: Ian you got you make yourself clear. I am unable to comprehend the steps(or issues as you call it)

Comment: Are you using a web server with the WebSphere plugin? The replication would only be a factor if you've actually switched cluster members, which, if you're using the WebSphere plugin, you shouldn't do as long as a session is active. Have you customized any of the session settings? Like, what are your Session Management > Custom tuning parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly writing the changed object back to the session before you forward/redirect? In at least some versions of WebSphere, in some configurations, you must do this to ensure the change is "committed".

(If I find a clear reference for this, I'll update my answer.)

Comment: What do you mean "explicitly"? I do a a "setAttribute" on the HttpSession before the redirect but don't do anything else....

Comment: That's what I meant. If you `getAttribute()` and change the contents of the object but then don't `setAttribute()` back, you could have a problem. But apparently that isn't your problem.